# How to scroll cut off text iOS tableview like a moving banner

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, uitableview

I have a tableview with dynamic data from a parsed xml file. I have set a default font size, and for most entries, it works okay. However, some have an entry that seems to be cut off.. and Apple simple adds "..." to the end.

Is there a way I can implement something like a slowly scrolling banner to accommodate this? And if not, is there a way I can make the text fit if it exceeds the size without making a global change to all entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for the slowly scrolling banner you would have to implement that yourself by animating your views.

If you don't expect your text to exceed the size by that much you could try using minimumScaleFactor in ios6:

```
[label setMinimumScaleFactor:.75f];
```

or minimumFontSizeSize for < ios6.
These essentially shrink the text to fit the frame.
p.s. you can configure these in interface builder

Comment: As of now I am not using labels (have not looked into creating a custom cell yet), but strings e.g. cell.textlabel.text = "some text";

Comment: the textLabel property on UITableViewCell is a UILabel. So you could do this: [cell.textLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:.75f] (.75 is just an example)